# Using Appium selenium python pytest how to launch google chrome and then launch android app (like facebook app)

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, pytest, appium

Hi everyone need assistance on this, how to automate android chrome browser and then launch android app like calculator app using Appium selenium python pytest.
i think this one is for the desired capabilities for chrome app, but how about the facebook app? and how to run them

```
{
  'platformName': 'Android',
  'platformVersion': '9.0',
  'deviceName': 'Android Emulator',
  'automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
  'browserName': 'Chrome'
}

class TestLaunch():

    @pytest.fixture
    def launch_chrome(self, test_args):
        if test_args["env"] == ENV().DEV:
            return {
                "username": "test@facebook.com",
                "password": "Password",
                "url": "https://m.facebook.com/"
                }
        elif test_args["env"] == ENV().PRD:
            return {
                "username": "test@facebook.com",
                "password": "Password",
                "url": "https://m.facebook.com/"
                }
    @pytest.fixture
    def launch_facebook(self, test_args):
        if test_args["env"] == ENV().DEV:
            return {
                "username": "test1@facebook.com",
                "password": "Password",
                }
        elif test_args["env"] == ENV().PRD:
            return {
                "username": "test1@facebook.com",
                "password": "Password",
                }
                
     def test_run_chrome(self, driver_mobile, launch_chrome):
     
      # how script code here to launch the chrome app

     def test_run_facebook(self, driver_mobile, launch_facebook):
     
      # how to script code here to launch the facebook app
```

how also to set the config file for this two launch, help is greatly appreciated